# Remote Desktop profiles vs. Scripted login

Tags: remote-desktop-services, windows-sbs-2011

I have a Windows SBS 2011 Essentials Server that has three clients with RDP connections. They need to use the same program but with three different serial numbers. The serial number resides in a simple text file in the same directory as the software. Can I create a batch file for login that switches out the text file for each RDP session? Or is there a way to use different profiles to have some sort of alias text file that is used only by each individual login? Like creating a variable in the .txt file that is different for each user. Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm assuming you already contacted the vendor and they told you that they don't support a RDS environment? Have you asked them about what you're trying to do and it wouldn't break their app? Lastly, it's baaaad practice to have users logging into your Domain Controller.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, having all of your users RDP into your DC is a "Windows Security 101" no no. You should figure out a different solution.

Second, make sure you're not violating your software license. Whenever installing anything like this on a shared computer, you should always check licensing.

As for a solution, you could have each user launch a batch file which puts the correct license in place and then launches the software. This will be much better than doing anything at login because another user logging in won't mess everything up.

Comment: As for a solution I think this will accomplish what I need. I understand that having them RDP into this box isn't the best practice, it happens to be the only option I have for this client. Thank you.